# Get name of matlab file one step up in stack

Tags: matlab, callstack

I'm writing a matlab script where I'd like to know the name of the script which is *one step up* in the stack. The reason I need this is that I'm writing a helper script to be called to assert some basic facts about the workspace before engaging in heavier calculations, and the helper script should be able to give error messages when calling the calculation scripts.

I've tried using `mfilename` and `dbstack`, but I do not manage to get anything but the name of the helper script from them.

To explain further, I have the following scripts:

- `verify_base_conditions`: the helper script, called on one of the first lines in
- `heavy_stuff_calculation` and
- `sweet_mother_of_algorithms`.
- `general_entry_point`: a script where I gather common workflows in cells

I try to keep the entry point script as small as possible, and refactor heavier calculations (or anything that needs more than a few lines, really) into task-based, re-usable scripts. If I, from the entry point script, call `sweet_mother_of_algorithms` and the basic conditions for this script to run are not fulfilled, I want to see an error message like

```
Error: this_cool_var must be defined when running sweet_mother_of_algorithms
general_entry_point line 15
```

I tried using

```
error(['this_cool_var must be defined when running ' mdfilename])
```

and other similar constructs, but I couldn't make the error message say anything but `verify_base_conditions`.

How do I find the name of the script running one level up in the stack?

(Note: I'm *not* interested in finding the script running at the *bottom* of the stack - that will almost always be `general_entry_point`. I'm just interested in getting the name of the script that called `verify_base_conditions`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dbstack` should work for this. I think this is an analogous set-up to yours:

```
a.m:
  b;

b.m:
  c;

c.m:
  stack = dbstack;
  for i=1:3
    disp(stack(i));
  end
```

When I run `a;`, this prints out the whole stack, including `b` (which I think it was you want - the second-top item on the call stack.

Alternatively, although this probably gives exactly the same result, you could throw and catch an error and look at its stack:

```
c.m:
  try
    error('What is on the call stack?');
  catch e
    for i=1:3
      disp(e.stack(i));
    end
  end
```

Comment: actually I'm surprised that your `error([... mdfilename])` code only prints verify_base_conditions. Errors normally print out the whole call stack.

Comment: I do get the entire call stack if I execute the entire file (e.g. by hitting <kbd>F5</kbd>), but not when I execute just one cell. Which is what I usually do...

Comment: ...but now, for some reason totally beyond my understanding, it suddenly started working. I'm using your first suggestion, and it works like a charm!